# Unable to get bar-code bounding box in right position on overlay Surfaceview

Tags: android, barcode-scanner, firebase-mlkit, android-camerax, google-mlkit

I'm using my CameraX with Firebase MLKit bar-code reader to detect barcode code. Application Identifies the bar-code without a problem. But I'm trying to add bounding box which shows the area of the barcode in CameraX preview in real-time. The Bounding box information is retrieved from the bar-code detector function. But It doesn't have nither right position nor size as you can see below.

[image]

This is my layout of the activity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/camera_capture_button"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:text="Take Photo"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:elevation="2dp" />

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/overlayView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
        android:id="@+id/previewView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

`SurfaceView` is used to draw this rectangle shape.

Barcode detection happens in the `BarcodeAnalyzer` class which implements `ImageAnalysis.Analyzer`. inside overwritten `analyze` function I retrieve the barcode data like below.

```
@SuppressLint("UnsafeExperimentalUsageError")
    override fun analyze(imageProxy: ImageProxy) {

        val mediaImage = imageProxy.image

        val rotationDegrees = degreesToFirebaseRotation(imageProxy.imageInfo.rotationDegrees)

        if (mediaImage != null) {

            val analyzedImageHeight = mediaImage.height
            val analyzedImageWidth = mediaImage.width

            val image = FirebaseVisionImage
                .fromMediaImage(mediaImage,rotationDegrees)

            detector.detectInImage(image)
                .addOnSuccessListener { barcodes ->

                    for (barcode in barcodes) {
                        val bounds = barcode.boundingBox
                        val corners = barcode.cornerPoints
                        val rawValue = barcode.rawValue

                        if(::barcodeDetectListener.isInitialized && rawValue != null && bounds != null){
                            barcodeDetectListener.onBarcodeDetect(
                                rawValue,
                                bounds,
                                analyzedImageWidth,
                                analyzedImageHeight
                            )
                        }
                    }

                    imageProxy.close()

                }
                .addOnFailureListener {
                    Log.e(tag,"Barcode Reading Exception: ${it.localizedMessage}")
                    imageProxy.close()
                }
                .addOnCanceledListener {
                    Log.e(tag,"Barcode Reading Canceled")
                    imageProxy.close()
                }

        }
    }
```

`barcodeDetectListener` is a reference to an interface I create to communicate this data back into my activity.

```
interface BarcodeDetectListener {
    fun onBarcodeDetect(code: String, codeBound: Rect, imageWidth: Int, imageHeight: Int)
}
```

In my main activity, I send these data to `OverlaySurfaceHolder` which implements the `SurfaceHolder.Callback`. This class is responsible for drawing a bounding box on overlayed `SurfaceView`.

```
override fun onBarcodeDetect(code: String, codeBound: Rect, analyzedImageWidth: Int,
                                 analyzedImageHeight: Int) {

        Log.i(TAG,"barcode : $code")
        overlaySurfaceHolder.repositionBound(codeBound,previewView.width,previewView.height,
            analyzedImageWidth,analyzedImageHeight)
        overlayView.invalidate()

    }
```

As you can see here I'm sending overlayed `SurfaceView` width and height for the calculation in `OverlaySurfaceHolder` class.

**OverlaySurfaceHolder.kt**

```
class OverlaySurfaceHolder: SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    var previewViewWidth: Int = 0
    var previewViewHeight: Int = 0
    var analyzedImageWidth: Int = 0
    var analyzedImageHeight: Int = 0

    private lateinit var drawingThread: DrawingThread
    private lateinit var barcodeBound :Rect

    private  val tag = OverlaySurfaceHolder::class.java.simpleName

    override fun surfaceChanged(holder: SurfaceHolder?, format: Int, width: Int, height: Int) {

    }

    override fun surfaceDestroyed(holder: SurfaceHolder?) {

        var retry = true
        drawingThread.running = false

        while (retry){
            try {
                drawingThread.join()
                retry = false
            } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
            }
        }
    }

    override fun surfaceCreated(holder: SurfaceHolder?) {
        drawingThread = DrawingThread(holder)
        drawingThread.running = true
        drawingThread.start()
    }

    fun repositionBound(codeBound: Rect, previewViewWidth: Int, previewViewHeight: Int,
                        analyzedImageWidth: Int, analyzedImageHeight: Int){

        this.barcodeBound = codeBound
        this.previewViewWidth = previewViewWidth
        this.previewViewHeight = previewViewHeight
        this.analyzedImageWidth = analyzedImageWidth
        this.analyzedImageHeight = analyzedImageHeight
    }

    inner class DrawingThread(private val holder: SurfaceHolder?): Thread() {

        var running = false

        private fun adjustXCoordinates(valueX: Int): Float{

            return if(previewViewWidth != 0){
                (valueX / analyzedImageWidth.toFloat()) * previewViewWidth.toFloat()
            }else{
                valueX.toFloat()
            }
        }

        private fun adjustYCoordinates(valueY: Int): Float{

            return if(previewViewHeight != 0){
                (valueY / analyzedImageHeight.toFloat()) * previewViewHeight.toFloat()
            }else{
                valueY.toFloat()
            }
        }

        override fun run() {

            while(running){

                if(::barcodeBound.isInitialized){

                    val canvas = holder!!.lockCanvas()

                    if (canvas != null) {

                        synchronized(holder) {

                            canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR)

                            val myPaint = Paint()
                            myPaint.color = Color.rgb(20, 100, 50)
                            myPaint.strokeWidth = 6f
                            myPaint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE

                            val refinedRect = RectF()
                            refinedRect.left = adjustXCoordinates(barcodeBound.left)
                            refinedRect.right = adjustXCoordinates(barcodeBound.right)
                            refinedRect.top = adjustYCoordinates(barcodeBound.top)
                            refinedRect.bottom = adjustYCoordinates(barcodeBound.bottom)

                            canvas.drawRect(refinedRect,myPaint)
                        }

                        holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas)

                    }else{
                        Log.e(tag, "Cannot draw onto the canvas as it's null")
                    }

                    try {
                        sleep(30)
                    } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }

                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Please can anyone point me out what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hey, did you find any solution for this? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: No, I'm dealing with the same kinda a problem with the MLKit object detection library. I'll post If I get any progress there.

Comment: Cool, I will also post if I get to something. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a very clear clue, but here are something you could try:

1. When you adjustXCoordinates, if previewWidth is 0, you return valueX.toFloat() directly. Could you add something logging to see it it actually falls into this case?  Also adding some logs to print the analysis and preview dimension could be helpful as well.
2. Another thing worth noting is that the image you sent to the detector could have different aspect ratio from the preview View area. For example, if your camera takes a 4:3 photo, it will send it to detector. However, if your View area is 1:1, it will crop some part of the photos to display it there. In that case, you need to take this into consideration as well when adjust coordinates. Base on my testing, the image will fit into the View area based on CENTER_CROP. If you want to be really careful, probably worth checking if this is documented in the camera dev site.

Hope it helps, more or less.

Answer (score 1):

I am no longer working on this project. However resonantly I worked on a camera application that uses Camera 2 API. In that application, there was a requirement to detect the object using the MLKit object detection library and show the bounding box like this on top of the camera preview. Faced the same issue like this one first and manage to get it to work finally. I'll leave my approach here. It might help someone.

Any detection library will do its detection process in a small resolution image compare to the camera preview image. When the detection library returns the combinations for the detected object we need to scale up to show it in the right position. it's called the scale factor. In order to make the calculation easy, it's better to select the analyze image size and preview image size in the same aspect ratio.

You can use the below function to get the aspect ratio of any size.

```
fun gcd(a: Long, b: Long): Long {
    return if (b == 0L) a else gcd(b, a % b)
}
    
fun asFraction(a: Long, b: Long): Pair<Long,Long> {
    val gcd = gcd(a, b)
    return Pair((a / gcd) , b / gcd)
}
```

After getting the camera preview image aspect ratio, selected the analyze image size like below.

```
val previewFraction = DisplayUtils
                      .asFraction(previewSize!!.width.toLong(),previewSize!!.height.toLong())
    
val analyzeImageSize = characteristics
                   .get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP)!!
                   .getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.YUV_420_888)
                   .filter { DisplayUtils.asFraction(it.width.toLong(), it.height.toLong()) == previewFraction }
                   .sortedBy { it.height * it.width}
                   .first()
```

Finaly when you have these two values you can calculate scale factor like below.

```
val scaleFactor = previewSize.width / analyzedSize.width.toFloat()
```

Finaly before the bounding box is drawn to the multiply each opint with scale factor to get correct screen coordinations.

Answer (score 0):

There is now an automated solution in CameraX for translating the coordinates from image coordinate system to screen preview coordinate system. You can use `LifecycleCameraController` and `PreviewView` (both from CameraX) with `MlKitAnalyzer`. If you connect them with each other and then set `CameraController.COORDINATE_SYSTEM_VIEW_REFERENCED` as `targetCoordinateSystem` in `MlKitAnalyzer`, then the coordinates of the barcode bounding box will be automatically translated to the `PreviewView` coordinates. They will still be in pixels though, so you need to translate them further to `dp` using `LocalDensity.current` and `toDp()` function (in Compose).

For detailed example solution in Jetpack Compose see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77698616/4990683). For a good explanation of the separation of concerns between `CameraController` and `PreviewView` see [this article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/camerax-learn-how-to-use-cameracontroller-e3ed10fffecf).

Answer (score -1):

if detect from bitmap, your reposition method will be right as i try.